# I try using floats to position some text but it is not even moving

Tags: css, position, css-position, positioning

I am trying to move the "A short summary of Erik Spikemann" along with the

under it. I want to place it next to the large photo of him as seen on the left side. I've tried doing a float left but for some reason that isn't working at all. I've attached my code.[Full photo of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCrLS.png)

Comment: @J Kardash: Maybe you want to paste the code or sections you suspect could be causing the problem on the page first?

Comment: It seems also that a part of your question is being hidden...  [ along with the (?)]. If it's a code, select it and click on the code button in the editor ({}).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Flexbox` or `Grid`. I'll give you an example for `Flexbox` that you can reflect on your own case and you can search for the other.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
 
 img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class = "container">
<img src = "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt = "Image" />

<p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

The idea here is you need to wrap your image and text with a parent `div` and make it a Flexbox.

```
flex-direction: row;     => Place the items side by side

justify-content: center; => Center the items horizontally

align-items: center;     => Center the items vertically
```

I encourage you to checkout this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about `Flexbox`